# Start stop daemon program

Tags: perl, unix

I've been using [`Proc::Daemon`](http://search.cpan.org/~deti/Proc-Daemon-0.14/lib/Proc/Daemon.pod) in an attempt to make a start/stop daemon script, something allows me to do:

```
X start
X stop
X status
```

etc. However, in the source code it looks like that [`Proc::Daemon`](http://search.cpan.org/~deti/Proc-Daemon-0.14/lib/Proc/Daemon.pod) uses either a "pid" file, or a search of the process table. I'm concerned with both of these approaches, firstly as "pid"s are reused, which may give the impression a service is up when it's actually down, and secondly that process table entries are easily faked, and the checking doesn't look particularly robust.

Is there any robust way to make a start/stop daemon script/program like I've described, or has someone already made one? Note that I haven't got root access, and I'm also on Solaris if that's important.

Comment: If you want neither a PID file nor a search through the process table then you have a chicken/egg problem. In order to check whether or not something is running you need to know its PID. That has to be stored somewhere where both the daemon that has been started and where the querying program can access the information. However you do that, that information can be removed by other processes (simple `rm`, delete entry from database, whatever). More control can be achieved with Linux-specific features like cgroups (see what systemd does).

Comment: @MoritzBunkus: For the sake of argument, assume other processes will not delete pid files etc. If they're doing that I've got bigger problems.

Answer (score 2):

Although pids are reused, I believe that they round-robin through a (large) fixed size set. e.g. on Solaris this used to be 30,000 (it may be different now). So 30,000 processes would have to start/finish before your pid was reused.

The approach used by Proc::Daemon doesn't look unreasonable and is a fairly common approach to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

An approach I use is to have the daemon process obtain an exclusive (write) lock on a file.

You can test to see if anyone is holding the lock by trying to obtain the lock yourself, and there are various ways of obtaining the PID of a process holding a lock on a file - i.e. fcntl and probably something in /proc.

Some words of advice:

1. Use local files (ie. not NFS) for locks.
2. Make sure the lock file exist before the daemon is started.
3. Never delete the lock file.

The kernel associates locks with the inode number of the file, so you always want the lock file to have the same inode number throughout all time. Deleting and recreating the lock file will change the inode associated with the lock.

A simple keep alive mechanism can be implemented as a cron job - the cron job just tries to spawn the daemon process every N minutes, and then have the daemon quietly exit if it can't obtain the exclusive lock.

Comment: Has someone implemented this? I don't want to reinvent the wheel.